# Git push fails due to large file size of a file I have already deleted from project/repo

Tags: git, push, gitignore, large-files, failed-installation

I deleted a video file from my project after considering the large file size. After deleting, I am unable to push to git. Git fails to push, stating that the file size is too large and breaches their file size limit of 100.
I have deleted the file and added it to git ignore file but am still unable to push changes.
Need to be able to push changes to git repo.
Need to keep this large file out of my project/repo.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots or can you share any code?

Comment: If you had it committed, and then made another commit to remove it, the file will still be in history. You will need to do an interactive rebase and remove it from all commits it was ever in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: Note that removing a file (`git rm bigfile`) and then committing (`git commit`) *does not remove the file from the repository*. The trick here is that Git doesn't *contain* files. What Git contains are *commits*. You made a new commit that lacks the file; meanwhile, other commits in the repository *have* the file. The `git push` command pushes *commits* (because that's what the repository has). You either have a whole commit, or you don't have that commit at all.

Comment: helpful, thank you!